# Debug Traefik/Yaegi Plugins in Devcontainers

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, vscode-devcontainer, traefik-plugins

I am currently developing a plugin for Traefik 2 that gets intepreted by yaegi. I am unable to debug `tokenValidate.go` because I receive this error message when I start the debugger.

[image: VSCODE error when launhing the debugger]

Based on the plugin documentation I have implemented the handler (code snippet)

```
func New(_ context.Context, next http.Handler, config *Config, _ string) (http.Handler, error) {

    tokenValidatePlugin := &TokenValidatePlugin{
        keys: make(map[string]interface{})
    }

   return tokenValidatePlugin
}
```

Current launch.json config

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Repository structure

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile.dev
├── app
│   ├── dynamic
│   │   └── dynamic.yml
│   ├── plugins-local
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── tokenValidate
│   │           ├── go.mod
│   │           ├── go.sum
│   │           ├── tokenValidate.go
│   │           └── vendor
│   │               └── modules.txt
│   └── traefik.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── dynamic-reference.yml
├── go.work
```

Comment: The debugger will be expecting your code to compile to an executable (i.e. `package main`); I suspect you are using `package tokenValidate` or similar?. The simplest way to debug this is probably to add a test (e.g. `tokenValidate_test.go`) and call `New` from within the test (but note that you will be debugging compiled code, which may work differently to code interpreted via Yaegi); if this rough approach works for you then let me know and I'll post an answer showing how I approach this (test has the option to use Yaegi or go compiler).